# Is there a way to replace or transform the result of a solr subquery to a multivalued field?

Tags: solr, subquery

I have documents with fields `id, relatedIds, value` and want to have the values of `value` of the documents with related ids in the result. My current solution is a subquery `p` with `fl: value,relatedIds,p:[subquery]` and `p.q: {!terms f=id v=$row.relatedIds}`. The response contains a field `p` with the result of the subquery.

Is there a way to get the result as a (multivalued) field `p` containing only the values of the field `value` of the result documents of the subquery?

Instead of

```
      {
        "value":"ABC",
        "relatedIds":["33344876", "33358333"],
        "p":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
            {
              "value":"DEF",
              "id":"33358333"},
            {
              "value":"GHI",
              "id":"33344876"}]
        }
      },...
```

I would like to have this result:

```
      {
        "value":"ABC",
        "relatedIds":["33344876", "33358333"],
        "p":["DEF","GHI"]
      },...
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a single solr query?

Would there even a way to combine this with the main result documents `value` field to

```
      {
        "value":"ABC",
        "relatedIds":["33344876", "33358333"],
        "values":["ABC","DEF","GHI"]
      },...
```

and possibly remove duplicate values from it?

Comment: Not an answer to your concrete question, but a different approach: As a _general_ rule in Solr (and other document based engines); could you resolve the values _when indexing_ instead of when querying? That leads to far more efficient searching and would make duplicate removal trivial; it'll require you to have a bit of logic of which documents to update when either of these values pointed to by the ids change. For your specific use case: Using a streaming expression might be more suitable, as you can add multiple instructions that aggregate and resolve different streams of results.

Comment: We thought about doing this when indexing, but this may get expensive when updates occur. An update on a top-level document would result in an update of all documents that spawn the "related" subtree.